# How integer (int) works?

Tags: php, integer, int

Can somebody explain me how it works integer (int) to prevent sqlinjections int $_GET parameter's ?
I look at php net but i don't get information that i need.
And if somebody know how work this:

```
$_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Please, tell me
Thanks for any answers!

Comment: What programming language are you asking about?

Comment: @Pavlo you mean to say that `$_GET` isn't an **immediate** giveaway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't execute harmful SQL with solely characters `0` through `9`.

And yes, someone does know how `filter_input_array` works: [the documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php)